Entity Framework Core : nullable FK update child issue
Some question has not group so I set FK as a optional field. When I am trying to update group, I get an error. If GroupId is required, then there is no problem.
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int id {  get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int? GroupId {  get; set; }
    public virtual Group? Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int id {  get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

Error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Question' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)

Is there any setting or something did I miss?

Add the code that is attempting to update the group. The error has nothing to do with the null-ability of the question-group association and everything to do with attempting to associate an untracked question (I.e a detached or new instance) for an existing question that the DbContext is already aware of and tracking.

As @StevePy pointed out - it has nothing to do with Group. The error clearly points to Question.Id. My guess is that you expect Id to be autogenerated by the database, but it isn't. So the value continues to be 0. To find out for sure, do what the error recommends - EnableSensitiveDataLogging()

Thank you. I will try EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
